# Can some one help me on below apex code i want to update this code as per governor limits

Tags: apex

```
public static void updatecasefields(List<Case> lstcase) {
        //List<Case> lstcase = new list<case>();
        ID devRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('CRM_CSR_Case').getRecordTypeId();
        for (Case cs: lstcase)  {
            if(cs.ID != null && cs.RecordTypeId == devRecordTypeId) {
                
                }
                
                List<CRM_CasePick__c> Casp = [SELECT Id, CRM_Carrier_Name__c,CRM_LOB__c, CRM_SLA_Turnaround_Time__c,CRM_Category__c, CRM_Issue_Sub_Type__c,CRM_Issue_Type__c,CRM_Turnaround_Time_Days__c FROM CRM_CasePick__c WHERE CRM_Carrier_Name__c = :cs.GiDP_CarrierName__c AND CRM_Category__c = :cs.CRM_Category__c AND CRM_Issue_Type__c = :cs.CRM_Issue_Type__c AND CRM_Issue_Sub_Type__c = :cs.CRM_Issue_Sub_Type__c AND CRM_LOB__c = :cs.CRM_Line_of_Business__c];                            
                for(CRM_CasePick__c CP: Casp) {
                   cs.CRM_Turnaround_Time_Days__c = cp.CRM_Turnaround_Time_Days__c;
                   cs.CRM_SLA_Turnaround_time__c = cp.CRM_SLA_Turnaround_Time__c;   
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the SOQL query from the for loop - best practice is to never run a query within a loop.

Right now it is running that query for every value of the initial list.  If the list is over 100 records, it will exceed the governor limit.